# How to change the value of a matrix array

Tags: matlab, matrix, indices

I have a question about how to change my coordinate system. I use a data file to create a spatially dependent variable (K_final) with my origin in the lower left hand corner; I would like to change the coordinate system to the center of the model grid at location (2,2,2) using the current coordinate system (cells). Each cell is 0.25 m/cell. The .dat file I call into the script is simply put a randomly generated correlated spatially dependent field, I have included a small portion of this field.

How do I go about changing the indices of the matrix without changing the values?

```
   A = [0.001 0.1 1 10 0.01 0.1 0.5 0.36 0.8 0.9 1 2 0.001 0.1 1 10 0.01 0.1 0.5 0.36 0.8 0.9 1 2 0.001 0.1 1 10 0.01 0.1 0.5 0.36 0.8 0.9 1 2 0.001 0.1 1 10 0.01 0.1 0.5 0.36 0.8 0.9 1 2 0.001 0.1 1 10 0.01 0.1 0.5 0.36 0.8 0.9 1 2 0.001 0.1 1 10 0.01 0.1 0.5 0.36 0.8 0.9 1 2 0.001 0.1 1 10 0.01 0.1 0.5 0.36]'

nx = 5; ny = 4; nz = 4;

k = 1;  average_K = 8;  
variance_K_high = 4;
variance_K_mid = 1;
variance_K_low = 0.25;


K_final = zeros(nx,ny,nz);

for a=1:(nx);
    for b=1:(ny);
        for c=1:(nz);
            K_final(a,b,c) = average_K*exp((variance_K_low^0.5)*A(k,1));
            k=k+1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks, Eric

Comment: It is quite unclear what you want, what the code does, and what is the reltionship between the two. Please try to explain more

Comment: "How do I go about changing the indices of the matrix without changing the values?" Are you talking about reshaping the matrix? see the `reshape()` function in matlab.

Comment: Currently I am trying to model 24 grids of 499x499 cells using matlab. My current system of measuring the distance is counting cells (0.25 m/cell). For instance, if I want to plot a line I must reference the location using the number of cells. Presently, The lower left hand corner is the first cell (1,1,1). I want to make the cell (2,2,2) the origin in the original question, where as the origin is currently set in the lower left. So my K_final array gives me x, y, z and variable. How do I change the x, y, and z coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Use Slice(X,Y,Z,V,Sx,Sy,Sz)...after defining what you want x, y, x